# New data ordering with python (pandas?) with repetition

Tags: python, multiple-columns, repeat

I would like to modify a file with the format below by using PYTHON.

From this:

```
0.0000 2.0200
0.0000 2.0400
0.0000 2.0800
0.0000 2.1200
0.0100 0.0000
0.0100 1.2400
0.0100 1.2600
0.0100 1.5800
0.0200 1.6600
0.0200 1.7000
0.0200 1.7800
0.0200 1.9800
```

to this:

```
0.0000 2.0200 2.0400 2.0800 2.1200
0.0100 0.0000 1.2400 1.2600 1.5800
0.0200 1.6600 1.7000 1.7800 1.9800
```

Does anyone has a suggestion?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u try pivot table?

Comment: No because python has priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Numpy `reshape` and `unique`:

```
data = [
 [0.0, 2.02],
 [0.0, 2.04],
 [0.0, 2.08],
 [0.0, 2.12],
 [0.01, 0.0],
 [0.01, 1.24],
 [0.01, 1.26],
 [0.01, 1.58],
 [0.02, 1.66],
 [0.02, 1.7],
 [0.02, 1.78],
 [0.02, 1.98]
]

# convert to numpy array
a = np.array(data)

# get unique indices
n = np.unique(a[:,0])

reshape the values to match the index length
v = np.reshape(a[:,1], (len(n),-1))

# re-combine the index and values
t = np.concatenate([n.reshape(-1,1),v],axis=1)
```